# Client side console application to get all site collections inside a particular SharePoint 2007 web application

Tags: sharepoint-2007, console-application, sitecollection

I need to create a console application to get all the site collections and subsites in a specific SharePoint 2007 web application. This application will run on client machine instead of SharePoint server.

I am not sure whether we can use object model for creating an application which runs outside SharePoint server. I thought of using Webs.asmx web service too, but could not find a suitable method to get the site collections.

Any help on this would be sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use object model for this as the console application will not be run on the server. For MOSS 2007, webservice is the only option.

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420128/accessing-all-sitecollections-on-a-sharepoint-server-with-webservice), Listing out all Site Collections is not possible using the out of the box web service. How about writing your own web service?

Comment: Thanks Shoban! I see that listing out all Site Collections is not possible using the out of the box web service, though I was able to get all the sub sites using Webs.asmx. Actually we have no remote access to the server, so the only get go is through web services.